# Xcode - Swift Programmatically select tablecell

Tags: swift, set, cell, selected

I need to know how to set the state of a tableviewcell to selected via code.

I tried the following:

```
let cell:TblCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as TblCell
cell.selected = false;
```

But this didn't work, even though it did not give any errors.

Should this have worked? or is this done differently?

Comment: you have to set it to true. Like this you are deselecting the cell

Answer (score 6):

```
tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .Middle)
```

Instead of `.Middle` you can use `.None` so the tableView doesn't scroll to the selected cell. `.Top` and `.Bottom` are also available options.